How to fix CMake warning "Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for ..."?
I'm building a ROS (Humble) workspace using 'colcon build'.
I'm getting the warning:
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:22 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target talker because files
  in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit directories:

    runtime library [libpython3.6m.so.1.0] in //lib64 may be hidden by files in:
      /nobackup/XXXXXXX/vobs_ros2/ros2_lin64/Python36/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:25 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target listener because
  files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [libpython3.6m.so.1.0] in //lib64 may be hidden by files in:
      /nobackup/XXXXXXX/vobs_ros2/ros2_lin64/Python36/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.

I see libpython3.6m.so.1.0 is in lib64 and in the Python local version I installed with conda: /nobackup/XXXXXXX/vobs_ros2/ros2_lin64/Python36/lib. It's definitely the same binary, so I'd like to get rid of this Warning.
According to this post: CMake cannot resolve runtime directory path, setting CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH should fix the problem. But even if I set COLCON_COMMON_ARGS="--cmake-args -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/nobackup/XXXXXXX/vobs_ros2/ros2_lin64/Python36", clean, remove CMakeCache.txt and retry, warning is still shown.
What's the good strategy to remove this warning? Is there no policy that could be set to remove it? Any other working strategy?
I searched for generate a safe runtime and may conflict with libraries in CMake source code but could not find any instance, I can't find where this warning comes from...
Note: I printed CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH from my CMakeLists.txt to verify it's set as expected. And I also tried with CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/nobackup/XXXXXXX/vobs_ros2/ros2_lin64/Python36/lib.
